# how to draw colored lines on a graph depending on the data

Tags: c#, charts

unsuccessfully trying to draw lines between the bubbles, depending on their movement. if the next value in the array is greater than the previous one, a green line will be drawn between them, but if the next value is less than the previous one, a red line will be drawn. I wrote a loop, but it does not work correctly - but the lines are redrawn. 
https://prnt.sc/sbcsjy
Here is the code I have:

```
            int[] year = { 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 };
            double max_axisX = 1.071;
            double intervalOffset_axisX = 0.266;

            ////                2010   2011   2012   2013   2014   2015   2016
            double[] ipp = { 0.241, 0.289, 0.129, 0.396, 0.682, 0.599, 1.00 };
            double[] pgc = { 0.154, 0.091, 0.176, 0.185, 0.144, 0.23, 0.23 };

       // show data in listbox
            for (int i = 0; i < ipp.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(" " + year[i] + " " + " " + ipp[i]);
            }
       // series
            Series series_1 = chart1.Series.Add("bubble-chart");
            Series series_2 = chart1.Series.Add("green-line");
            Series series_3 = chart1.Series.Add("red-line");


            // series 1
            series_1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble;
            series_1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
            series_1.BorderWidth = 1;
            series_1.Color = Color.Transparent;
            series_1.BorderColor = Color.Black;
            series_1["BubbleScaleMin"] = "0";

            // series 2
            series_2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series_2.Color = Color.Green;
            series_2.BorderWidth = 10;

            // series 3
            series_3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series_3.Color = Color.Red;
            series_3.BorderWidth = 3;

            // plotting chart
            for (int i = 0; i < ipp.Length; i++)
            {
                series_1.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i], ipp[i]);
                series_1.Points[i].Label = Convert.ToString(year[i]);
                series_1.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 12);
                series_1.LabelBackColor = Color.White;
                series_1.LabelBorderColor = Color.Black;
            }
            // plotting lines

            for (int i = 0; i < ipp.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (ipp[i + 1] > ipp[i])
                {

                    series_2.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i]);
                    series_2.Points.AddXY(ipp[i + 1], pgc[i + 1]);

                }
                else if (ipp[i] > ipp[i + 1])
                {

                    series_3.Points.AddXY(ipp[i + 1], pgc[i + 1]);
                    series_3.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i]);

                }
            }
```

Please tell me where I'm wrong.
Must be like https://prnt.sc/sbct4o

Comment: Line charts will always connect all points. So, it may be simpler to use only one Series for those extra lines. You can color each line separately by coloring its 2nd point. Or you can add transparent points to skip segments. Modify the is else clauses to always add a point to each series, but some with a transparent color..

Comment: `if (i<ipp.Length-1) {int p = series_2.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i]); series_2.Points[p].Color = ipp[i + 1] > ipp[i] ? Color.Green : Color.Red;}` - Puttin this in the 1st loop and omitting the 2nd one should work..

Comment: it’s just super, draws as I wanted it, excellent. But there is a small point, does not connect with the last point https://prnt.sc/sbft8t
is it posible to add in the end off array empty value, or somthink like that?

Comment: Ah, yes, I think I messed it up a little. Try this `int p = series_2.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i]);  if (i<ipp.Length-1) {int p = series_2.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i]); if (i  <ipp.Length-1) series_2.Points[p].Color = ipp[i - 1] > ipp[i] ? Color.Green : Color.Red;}`

Comment: The index was outside the bounds of the array :D

Comment: and i cant understand why i have that https://prnt.sc/sbg308
if value of 2012 lessthan 2013, but its drawing red

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213189/discussion-between-taw-and-5tka).